# C pointing char** to another starting position?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I currently have something of the form

```
char** args = { "a", "s", "d", "f" };
```

What I want is

```
char** newArgs = { "s", "d", "f" };
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: That is not valid C. I suppose you should have meant `char * args[] = { "a", "s", "d", "f" };`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
newargs = args + 1;
```

Or maybe:

```
newargs = &args[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want an independent set of pointers:

```
char **newArgs = calloc(3, sizeof(*newArgs));
memcpy(newArgs, args + 1, 3*sizeof(*newArgs));
```

otherwise:

```
char **newArgs = args + 1;
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Depends what the aim is.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
newArgs = &args[1];
```

Comment: The motivation was, that your first version was simply wrong.

Comment: @Nobody I was too fast in typing. I corrected myself in less than a minute anyway. Not sure this deserves 3 votes down...

Comment: Well people voted on the false one. There is this problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/vote-cant-be-changed-if-answer-is-edited-too-quickly Just edit your answer one more time and people can change their votes.

Comment: A was not too until I hit exactly this problem.